# How to compare classes and interfaces?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Can anybody explain me how to compare `KClass`es and interfaces among themselves? I know how to check if classes or interfaces are equal but I don't understand how to check if A class is a superclass of B class, etc.

```kotlin
interface IB {}
interface IC : IB {}

open class A {}
open class B : A() {}
open class C : B(), IC {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  if (B::class == B::class) { println("B class is equal to B class") }
  if (IB::class == IB::class) { println("IB interface is equal to IB interface") }
    
  if (A::class ??? B::class) { println("A class is parent of B class") }
  if (A::class ??? C::class) { println("A class is superclass of C class") }
    
  if (C::class ??? IC) { println("C class implements IC interface") }
  if (IC ??? IB) { println("IC interface implements IB interface") }
}
```

Comment: Klutter library also has extensions for these comparisons of `Class` and `KClass`, as well as to `Type` and `KType` which you might encounter with Kotlin reflection.  https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/master/reflect-core-jdk6/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/reflect/Types.kt and more in https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/master/reflect-full-jdk6/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/reflect/full/Types.kt

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Kotlin reflection doesn't have an API for retrieving information about `KClass` hierarchy, so the only way to check if one `KClass` is superclass or subclass of another `KClass` is to compare corresponding java classes:

```
interface IB {}
interface IC : IB {}

open class A {}
open class B : A() {}
open class C : B(), IC {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  if (B::class == B::class) { println("B class is equal to B class") }
  if (IB::class == IB::class) { println("IB interface is equal to IB interface") }

  if (A::class.java.isAssignableFrom(B::class.java)) { println("A class is parent of B class") }
  if (A::class.java.isAssignableFrom(C::class.java)) { println("A class is superclass of C class") }

  if (IC::class.java.isAssignableFrom(C::class.java)) { println("C class implements IC interface") }
  if (IB::class.java.isAssignableFrom(IC::class.java)) { println("IC interface implements IB interface") }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You can also define two extension functions that will make this kind of checks a bit nicer:

```
inline fun <reified L : Any, reified R : Any> isSubClassOf(): Boolean {
  return R::class.java.isAssignableFrom(L::class.java)
}

inline fun <reified L : Any, reified R : Any> isSuperClassOf(): Boolean {
  return L::class.java.isAssignableFrom(R::class.java)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  if (isSubClassOf<B, B>()) { println("B class is equal to B class") }
  if (isSubClassOf<IB, IB>()) { println("IB interface is equal to IB interface") }

  if (isSuperClassOf<A, B>()) { println("A class is parent of B class") }
  if (isSuperClassOf<A, C>()) { println("A class is superclass of C class") }

  if (isSubClassOf<C, IC>()) { println("C class implements IC interface") }
  if (isSubClassOf<IC, IB>()) { println("IC interface implements IB interface") }
}
```

Comment: wow, I would expect `compareTo` operator to be overloaded for that

Comment: @voddan you can not define a `compareTo` operator for partially ordered sets

Comment: @VladimirMironov I think @voddan mean something like [this](https://gist.github.com/maxd/8f967002343865dd40a7). As you can see possible to override `compareTo` and use `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` operators for compare classes (for example such syntax using in Ruby). I hope kotlin.reflect will have something like this in the future.

Comment: @maxd stdlib will never have such operator because it's just impossible to properly implement `compareTo` for `KClass`. Your implementation violates   `compareTo` contract, because it should never throw.

Comment: @VladimirMironov this contract to never throw out of `compareTo` exists in Java, but does not in Kotlin (no checked exceptions as a concept). I think the implementation mentioned by @maxd makes sense and violates nothing since it is invisible from Java

Comment: There are extensions: [isSuperclassOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/is-superclass-of.html) [isSubclassOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/is-subclass-of.html). So there is no need to define your own. Make sure to include `kotlin-reflect` library though