# Kotlin class literals with empty left hand side are not yet supported?

Tags: reflection, kotlin, type-safety

I am trying to check if a type conforms to a another type with an if expression like so:

```
if (String::class is Any::class)
```

This gives me the error class literals with empty left hand side are not yet supported. Can anyone elaborate on that error and/or tell me how I should be doing this check?

edit (clarification): I can't do an equality check because I need to know if the class on the left either matches the class on the right or is a subclass of it. So if an instance of the class on the left can be safely cast to the class on the right.

Basically I need the equivalent of:

```
if ("A string" is Any)
```

But without having a String instance, String just being used an example here.

Comment: My colleague found another SO post which says Kotlin has no way to do this and the only way is to use Java reflection (assuming you're targeting JVM). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851719/how-to-compare-classes-and-interfaces/35852445#35852445

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message is that the `is` check expects a class name and not a reference to a KClass on the right side.  The message itself might be a little unclear.  But the same applies in Java, you would not use `instanceOf` operator but instead would call `isAssignableFrom`.

For help on solving the problem, you have examples that can be found in Github...

In the [Klutter library](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter) are examples of a lot of combinations of instanceOf style checking between `Class`, `KClass`, `Type` and `KType` as well as primitives.  You can copy ideas from there.  There are many combinations that you might want to have covered in the long run.

Here is a sampling of [a big mix of extensions](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/v2/reflect/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/reflect/Types.kt) for checking if one type is assignable from the other.  A few examples are:

```
fun <T : Any, O : Any> KClass<T>.isAssignableFrom(other: KClass<O>): Boolean {
    if (this.java == other.java) return true
    return this.java.isAssignableFrom(other.java)
}

fun <T : Any> KClass<T>.isAssignableFrom(other: Class<*>): Boolean {
    if (this.java == other) return true
    return this.java.isAssignableFrom(other)
}

fun KClass<*>.isAssignableFromOrSamePrimitive(other: KType): Boolean {
    return (this.java as Type).isAssignableFromOrSamePrimitive(other.javaType) 
}

fun KClass<*>.isAssignableFromOrSamePrimitive(other: Type): Boolean {
    return (this.java as Type).isAssignableFromOrSamePrimitive(other)
}

fun Type.isAssignableFromOrSamePrimitive(other: Type): Boolean {
    if (this == other) return true
    if (this is Class<*>) {
        if (other is Class<*>) {
            return this == other.kotlin.javaObjectType || this == other.kotlin.javaPrimitiveType ||
                    this.isAssignableFrom(other)
        }
        return this.isAssignableFrom(other.erasedType())
    }
    return this.erasedType().isAssignableFrom(other.erasedType())
}

// ... and so on for every permutation of types
```

See the [linked source for all permutations](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/v2/reflect/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/reflect/Types.kt).

And you will need this [`erasedType()` extension](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/blob/v2/reflect/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/reflect/TypeInfo.kt#L25-L44) used by the above samples -- which goes from a `Type` back to a `Class` (after type erasure):

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") fun Type.erasedType(): Class<Any> {
    return when (this) {
        is Class<*> -> this as Class<Any>
        is ParameterizedType -> this.getRawType().erasedType()
        is GenericArrayType -> {
            // getting the array type is a bit trickier
            val elementType = this.getGenericComponentType().erasedType()
            val testArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(elementType, 0)
            testArray.javaClass
        }
        is TypeVariable<*> -> {
            // not sure yet
            throw IllegalStateException("Not sure what to do here yet")
        }
        is WildcardType -> {
            this.getUpperBounds()[0].erasedType()
        }
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Should not get here.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess it wouldn't be clear if Kotlin used the `is` operator differently between a `KClass` and another `KClass` as it does between an instance and a type which is why what I was trying to do doesn't work. Anyway I made this little infix function to imitate the functionality. However it only works with JVM target of course since it's using Java reflection. This is going off of the [answer given in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851719/how-to-compare-classes-and-interfaces/35852445#35852445).

```
infix fun <T : Any, C : Any> KClass<T>.can(comparate: KClass<C>) =
   comparate.java.isAssignableFrom(this.java)
```

This will allow you to do exactly what I was trying to do but with the `can` function instead of the is operator like so:

```
if(String::class can Any::class)
```